# Why is my image slideshow not working?

Tags: javascript, html, image, xhtml

I'm programming an image slideshow and for some reason it isn't working. Below I have the `HTML`:

```
<div id = "images">
    <img id = "imageSrc" />
</div>
```

Here is my `JavaScript` which is what I'm using to change my images:

```
var images = document.getElementById("imageSrc");
var x = 0;
var imagesArray = ["image.png", "anotherImage.png", "yetAnotherImage.png"];

function changeImages() {
    images.src = imagesArray[x];
    if (x < 2) {
        x++;
    } else {
        x = 0;
    }
    alert(images.src);
}

setInterval(changeImages(), 3000);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3ctt7q49/)**

Why am I not getting an alert every 3 seconds with my image code? The images aren't switching so where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Any errors showing in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling a function as an argument, don't use parentheses.

```
setInterval(changeImages, 3000);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3ctt7q49/3)**

If you did need to pass arguments in the function call, wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var myArg;
    changeImages(myArg);
}, 3000);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3ctt7q49/2)**

Answer (score 3):

Remove the curly braces when you are calling the function

Change 
        `setInterval(changeImages(), 3000);`

to

```
    setInterval(changeImages, 3000);
```

Comment: This and if you want to start with your initial array image, just add the `images.src = imagesArray[x];` code right before the `function changeImages()` line as well... if you don't want to put an initial src in your html image.  Keep the other one though.